# OpenCV 4.0 and AMD processor Python

Tags: python, opencv, gpu, opencl, amd-gpu

Can I somehow use my AMD GPU to speed up computations in my Python script? I'm doing object detection using OpenCV 4.0 with `cv2.dnn` module.

Basing on similar questions I've tried to use `cv2.UMat` but it doesn't speed up computations, so I assume that the script was still run on my poor CPU.

GPU info: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but AFAICT, that's a fairly old GPU (pre-GCN architecture). Those were not really suited for GPGPU computations. It should be still possible to install OpenCL drivers, but i cannot guarantee anything as i can't try it.

I assume you're on linux. [Here](https://community.amd.com/thread/222956) is an article on how to use older AMD GPUs with Linux. You would have to follow steps in "Running Open CL on old cards" section, which involve installing Ubuntu 14.04 and fglrx 15.12 drivers.